# Watching any changes in ngmodel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined ng-model ad

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="check" ng-model="params.privacy">
```

I have my controller code as

```
$scope.params={
    privacy:true,  
    status: false
   }
```

How to watch any changes of the terms inside the $scope.params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$scope.$watch('params.privacy', function(new, old) {
   // triggered when `params.privacy` is changed
});
```

Or if you want to watch all properties, use `deep` watch:

```
$scope.$watch('params', function(new, old) {
   // triggered when any `params` property is changed
}, true);
```